# How do I loop a script through all pages but the first one?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm *very* new to all this. I'm trying to write a script that sorts sheets by descending date order each time a new row is entered. I need the script to run on all pages but the first (the summary page). I've gotten close (I can get the script to run on a specified page), but don't know how to

- exclude a page or
- have it start running the script on the second page.

Here's the code so far. It appears there is a TypeError in the line that reads, "var editedCell = shs.getActiveCell();"

```
function onEdit(event){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shs = ss.getSheets(), num = shs.length;
  var sheetName = [] 

  for(var i = 1; i<num; i++);
    var editedCell = shs.getActiveCell();
    var columnToSortBy = 1;
    var tableRange = "A2:G99"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error: `shs` is an array, since you populate it with `ss.getSheets()`, so it doesn't have a method `getActiveCell()`. However, the *elements* of the array has that method.

You are also referencing a variable `sheet`, which you haven't defined anywhere.

Currently, your code is more suitable for going through a single sheet, you need to iterate through the `shs` array to have it operate on all sheets.

The following function will go through all cells in all sheets:

```
function onEdit(event){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shs = ss.getSheets(), num = shs.length;
  var sheetName = [] 

  for (var sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < shs.length; sheetIdx++) {
      var sheet = shs[sheetIdx];

      for(var i = 1; i<num; i++) {
      ...
   }
}
```

But you wanted to skip the first sheet, so let's start with element `1` in the array (since the array is `0`-based, element `1` is the second sheet):

```
function onEdit(event){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shs = ss.getSheets(), num = shs.length;
  var sheetName = [] 

  for (var sheetIdx = 1; sheetIdx < shs.length; sheetIdx++) {
      var sheet = shs[sheetIdx];

      for(var i = 1; i<num; i++) {
        var editedCell = shs.getActiveCell();
        var columnToSortBy = 1;
        var tableRange = "A2:G99"; // What to sort.

        if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
          var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
          range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false });
        }
      }

   }
}
```

As for your comment, your code

```
function onEdit(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for (var n in ss.getSheets()) {
        var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];
        var name = sheet.getName();
        if (name == 'Dashboard') 
           return;
        var editedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
        var columnToSortBy = 1;
        var tableRange = "A2:G99";
        if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {
            var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
            range.sort({column: columnToSortBy, ascending: false});
        }
    }
}
```

could work, if you replace `return` with `continue`. You don't want `return`, it ends the script. `continue` skips to the next element in the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, here is the link to the spreadsheet. I'm running it in the scripts editor. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Jz4Rm3OSGyMZDla-LxlG8T9NY0ockrzmyJUakYTGzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's because of `name != 'Dashboard'`. That means that only if the name of the sheet is `Dashboard`, the rest of the `for` loop will run. You probably want `name == 'Dashboard'`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That makes sense. And what you said about the *Play* button makes sense, too. I was able to make edits on both the 2nd and 3rd pages and see the sheets reorder themselves. You've been so helpful. There is a non-profit in NYC that is singing your praises. Thanks, again.